# Haskell can't deduce type equality

Tags: haskell, automatic-differentiation

I have the following code, which does not compile:

```
  import Numeric.AD

  data Trainable a b = forall n . Floating n =>  Trainable ([n] -> a -> b) (a -> b -> [n] -> n) 

  trainSgdFull :: (Floating n, Ord n) => Trainable a b -> [n] -> a -> b -> [[n]]
  trainSgdFull (Trainable _ cost) init input target =  gradientDescent (cost input target) init
```

I want to use the Trainable type to represent machine learning systems trainable by gradient descent. The first arguemnt would be the transfer function, and the sencond would be the cost function, a is the input type, and b is the output/target type, and the list contains the learnable parameters.
The compiler complains this:

```
 src/MachineLearning/Training.hs:12:73:
Could not deduce (n1 ~ ad-3.3.1.1:Numeric.AD.Internal.Types.AD s n)
from the context (Floating n, Ord n)
  bound by the type signature for
             trainSgdFull :: (Floating n, Ord n) =>
                             Trainable a b -> [n] -> a -> b -> [[n]]
  at src/MachineLearning/Training.hs:12:3-95
or from (Floating n1)
  bound by a pattern with constructor
             Trainable :: forall a b n.
                          Floating n =>
                          ([n] -> a -> b) -> (a -> b -> [n] -> n) -> Trainable a b,
           in an equation for `trainSgdFull'
  at src/MachineLearning/Training.hs:12:17-32
or from (Numeric.AD.Internal.Classes.Mode s)
  bound by a type expected by the context:
             Numeric.AD.Internal.Classes.Mode s =>
             [ad-3.3.1.1:Numeric.AD.Internal.Types.AD s n]
             -> ad-3.3.1.1:Numeric.AD.Internal.Types.AD s n
  at src/MachineLearning/Training.hs:12:56-95
  `n1' is a rigid type variable bound by
       a pattern with constructor
         Trainable :: forall a b n.
                      Floating n =>
                      ([n] -> a -> b) -> (a -> b -> [n] -> n) -> Trainable a b,
       in an equation for `trainSgdFull'
       at src/MachineLearning/Training.hs:12:17
Expected type: [ad-3.3.1.1:Numeric.AD.Internal.Types.AD s n1]
               -> ad-3.3.1.1:Numeric.AD.Internal.Types.AD s n1
  Actual type: [n] -> n
In the return type of a call of `cost'
In the first argument of `gradientDescent', namely
  `(cost input target)'
```

Is the basic concept right? If it is, how could I make the code compile?

Comment: Why do you need the forall? Why not do `data Trainable a b n = Trainable ([n] -> a -> b) (a -> b -> [n] -> n)` and `trainSgdFull :: (Floating n, Ord n) => Trainable a b n -> [n] -> a -> b -> [[n]]`? Would that work?

Comment: Or (having had a glance at Numeric.AD) would you need `trainSgdFull :: forall n.(Floating n, Ord n) => Trainable a b n -> [n] -> a -> b -> [[n]]`. <Frustrated, Andrew stares around his work computer for ghc and finds none.>

Comment: I would like to avoid using n in the Trainable type constructor, because I would like the same Trainable to be able to work with Doubles, and with AD types.

Comment: Your code compiles as is for me, given a definition of `gradientDescent = undfined`. More context is needed. (AFAICT `gradientDescent` is not in `Numeric.AD`).

Comment: According to [Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/ad/3.4/doc/html/Numeric-AD.html#v:gradientDescent), and ghci gradientDescent is in Numeric.AD.  It can compile with undefined since undefined will simply match any type.

Comment: @laci37: aha, you are right, I looked at the old version of AD.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that

```
data Trainable a b = forall n . Floating n =>  Trainable ([n] -> a -> b) (a -> b -> [n] -> n)
```

means that in

```
Trainable transfer cost
```

the type `n` used is lost. All that is known is that there is some type `Guessme` with a `Floating` instance such that

```
transfer :: [Guessme] -> a -> b
cost :: a -> b -> [Guessme] -> Guessme
```

You can build `Trainable`s with functions that only work for `Complex Float`, or only for `Double`, or ...

But in

```
trainSgdFull :: (Floating n, Ord n) => Trainable a b -> [n] -> a -> b -> [[n]]
trainSgdFull (Trainable _ cost) init input target =  gradientDescent (cost input target) init
```

you are trying to use `cost` with whatever `Floating` type is supplied as an argument.

The `Trainable` was built to work with type `n0`, the user supplies type `n1`, and those may or may not be the same. Thus the compiler can't deduce they are the same.

If you don't want to make `n` a type parameter of `Trainable`, you need to make it wrap polymorphic functions that work with *every* `Floating` type the caller supplies

```
data Trainable a b
    = Trainable (forall n. Floating n => [n] -> a -> b)
                (forall n. Floating n => a -> b -> [n] -> n)
```

(needs `Rank2Types`, or, since that is in the process of being deprecated, `RankNTypes`).

Comment: The OP probably wanted to wrap a polymorphic type all along, but ended up with an existential, *because we use `forall` instead of `exists` in Haskell*. I fall in this trap every time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works for this module, but I have a follow-up [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14738197/haskell-still-cant-deduce-type-equality) @n.m. was right I really wanted polymorphic types.