# Haskell still can't deduce type equality

Tags: haskell

This question is a follow up on the question [Haskell can't deduce type equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14734702/haskell-cant-deduce-type-equality).
I have tried implementing a basic polynomial approximator using the Trainable type described in my previous question with the following code:

```
module MachineLearning.Polynomial
       (polynomial,
        polynomialTrf
       ) where
import MachineLearning.Training
import MachineLearning.Utils

polynomialTrf :: Floating n => [n] -> n -> n
polynomialTrf coeff var = helper 0 coeff var 0 where
  helper _ [] var acc = acc
  helper 0 (c:cs) var acc = helper 1 cs var c 
  helper deg (c:cs) var acc = helper (deg+1) cs var (acc+(c*(var^deg)))

polynomialCost :: Floating n => n -> n -> [n] -> n
polynomialCost var target coeff = sqcost (polynomialTrf coeff var) target

polynomialSV :: (Floating n) => Trainable n n
polynomialSV = Trainable polynomialTrf polynomialCost
```

Here `sqcost` is just `sqcost a b = (a-b) ^ 2`. I get the following error message from the compiler:

```
src/MachineLearning/Polynomial.hs:18:26:
    Could not deduce (n1 ~ n)
    from the context (Floating n)
      bound by the type signature for
                 polynomialSV :: Floating n => Trainable n n
      at src/MachineLearning/Polynomial.hs:18:1-53
    or from (Floating n1)
      bound by a type expected by the context:
                 Floating n1 => [n1] -> n -> n
      at src/MachineLearning/Polynomial.hs:18:16-53
      `n1' is a rigid type variable bound by
           a type expected by the context: Floating n1 => [n1] -> n -> n
           at src/MachineLearning/Polynomial.hs:18:16
      `n' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for polynomialSV :: Floating n => Trainable n n
          at src/MachineLearning/Polynomial.hs:18:1
    Expected type: [n] -> n1 -> n1
      Actual type: [n] -> n -> n
    In the first argument of `Trainable', namely `polynomialTrf'
    In the expression: Trainable polynomialTrf polynomialCost

src/MachineLearning/Polynomial.hs:18:40:
    Could not deduce (n ~ n1)
    from the context (Floating n)
      bound by the type signature for
                 polynomialSV :: Floating n => Trainable n n
      at src/MachineLearning/Polynomial.hs:18:1-53
    or from (Floating n1)
      bound by a type expected by the context:
                 Floating n1 => n -> n -> [n1] -> n1
      at src/MachineLearning/Polynomial.hs:18:16-53
      `n' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for polynomialSV :: Floating n => Trainable n n
          at src/MachineLearning/Polynomial.hs:18:1
      `n1' is a rigid type variable bound by
           a type expected by the context: Floating n1 => n -> n -> [n1] -> n1
           at src/MachineLearning/Polynomial.hs:18:16
    Expected type: n -> n -> [n1] -> n1
      Actual type: n -> n -> [n] -> n
    In the second argument of `Trainable', namely `polynomialCost'
    In the expression: Trainable polynomialTrf polynomialCost
```

My question is where is the problem coming from? How can I solve it? For me it feels clear the those two types are equal, so there is the possibility that I misunderstand something in the type system.

Comment: the code you have here wants an existential type which is what you had originally!

Comment: Do you really need to hide the `n` in `Trainable`? Can't you simply make it `Trainable n a b`?

Comment: I have quckly rewritten the `Training` module so it uses `Trainable n a b` but it won't compile, it says that it can't match `n` with `AD` in `trainSgdFull`

Comment: You might be interested in reading [Haskell Antipattern: Existential Typeclass](http://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/). It shows how to avoid existential types in some cases, although I'm not sure if it will be applicable in your case.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid the rank 2 type

```
data Trainable a b
    = Trainable (forall n. Floating n => [n] -> a -> b)
                (forall n. Floating n => a -> b -> [n] -> n)
```

won't help you. I concentrated only on the type error in the other question, and didn't notice that `Floating` isn't rich enough to make that really usable. Since you can't generically convert from a `Floating` type to some other type or to a `Floating` type from anything but `Real`s (`realToFrac`), you can't write many interesting functions of the given polymorphic types in general, sorry.

The problem here is that the above type demands that the functions passed to the `Trainable` constructor work for all `Floating` types `n` (whatever the specified `a` and `b`), but the implementations `polynomialTrf` and `polynomialCost` only work for one specific `Floating` type, the one that is given as (both) the parameters. `polynomialTrf` has the type `Floating n => [n] -> n -> n`, but it would need to have the type `(Floating n, Floating f) => [f] -> n -> n` to be eligible to be passed to the `Trainable` constructor.

With a third type parameter, you would have

```
Trainable polynomialTrf polynomialCost :: Floating n => Trainable n n n
```

and for `trainSgdFull`, you would need the type

```
trainSgdFull :: (Floating n, Ord n, Mode s) => Trainable a b (AD s n) -> [n] -> a -> b -> [[n]]
```

to be able to use `gradientDescent`.

I don't know how a proper solution to your problem might look like.

Comment: The problem with `polynomialSV :: Floating n => Trainable n n n` would be that, I had to supply the training input and target as `AD`.

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do, so I don't understand what the problem really is, sorry. I _might_ understand if you explained what you want in more breadth.